# how to apply validation only if form fields is dirty in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

i have following html code :

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="internal" placeholder="intName" ng-model="exp.int">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="external" placeholder="extName" ng-model="exp.ext">
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

i want to do validation only if **internal** field and **external** field is dirty and have to apply validation like number or pattern match.how is it possible in controller?

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to avoid the validation error until the user has changed something?

Comment: yeah,how is it possible ? @deitch

Comment: There are a bunch of articles on it. I have used it only a bit so far, so I won't mark it as an answer, just put links in the comments

Comment: Look at http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/    http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/        http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/11/validation-in-angular-forms-part-1   There are a bunch more, but these point in the right direction. I don't know if the angular team has plans to update validation to have a "mark only if dirty" option, but here you go.

Comment: FYI, those are the ones I used as reference.